# What is $\gcd(x,y)$ in this case?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

> Suppose there are integers $a,b,x$ and $y$ such that $ax +by = 5$, and $5$ does not divide $x$. What is $\gcd(x,y)$?

I have been trying to figure out this question for some time. However, I do not even know how to start.

I tried rewriting the equation:

$$5 = ax+by$$

Then I made everything into mod $x$,

$$5\pmod{x} \equiv ax\pmod{x} + by\pmod{x}$$

$$5\equiv by\pmod{x}$$

I couldn't figure out how to continue from here.

Can anyone help me with this? I am very stuck and I do not know how to solve this problem.

Comment: The greatest common divisor of $x$ and $y$ must divide any number of the form $ax+by$. If you can express $5$ in that form, what does that tell you about the greatest common divisor? This is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Hint: Note that $2+3=5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d>0$ be a common divisor of $x$ and $y$ then $d$ divides $ax+by=5$.
Since $5$ is prime it follows that $d=1$ or $d=5$. Now, we note the assumption "5 does not divide $x$". What may we conclude about $d$? What is $\gcd(x,y)$, i.e. the greatest common divisor of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: So since d is the common divisor of $x$ and $y$ and $ax+by=5$. Then, 5 can only be divided by $1$ or itself. And "5 does not divide x", therefore $d=1$. Is this right?

Comment: @BryanHii Yes, $d=1$ is the only positive common divisor and therefore $\gcd(x,y)=1$.